# C# ComboBox get Key and Text in autocomplete

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, combobox, autocomplete

I am having trouble recovering the Value and the key of the combobox with autocomplete.

I execute the code upon accessing the form:

```
Dictionary<string, string> comboSource = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (int i = 0; i < products.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  comboSource.Add(dr["id"].ToString(), dr["name"].ToString());
}

autoCompleteCombo.DataSource = new BindingSource(comboSource, null);
autoCompleteCombo.DisplayMember = "Value";
autoCompleteCombo.ValueMember = "Key";
autoCompleteCombo.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;


private void autoCompleteCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string key = ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)autoCompleteCombo.SelectedItem).Key;
    string value = ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)autoCompleteCombo.SelectedItem).Value;

    MessageBox.Show(key + " / " + value);
}
```

If I do not type anything, just move the up and down arrow, it works.

[image]

If I type something, it does not work.

[image]

There is no other event on the combobox.

Comment: While typing, you are letting a user filter one or more items from the list. The user has to press `Enter` or choose an item from the list (with the cursors or a mouse) to trigger the `SelectedIndexChange` (or `SelectionChangeCommitted`) event. This is the standard behaviour. I think most of the people are used to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.